# Cordova plugin googleplus not getting installed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, google-authentication

I am developing an ionic 1 application with firebase integration. I want to add google plus authentication and use [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) for the same.
On executing the function I get error - **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'googleplus' of undefined"**

I see that this is probably because the plugin is not getting installed properly.
I removed and added plugin again but still I get the same error.

**Ionic info**

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Version: 1.3.2
Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.0.16
OS: null
Node Version: v6.10.0
```

I referred [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/438) post and Updating cordova and android also doesn't help.

The command **cordova plugin list** shows the plugin and I can see that in config.xml and package.json files and the repository is cloned in plugins folder.

Commands I tried to install the plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --save
cordova prepare
```

I tried with ionic too

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your platforms, try adding the plugin again and re-add your platforms. Is this working ?